# Warning: ISO C forbids an empty translation unit

Tags: c, macros

In a header file I have the following code which gives me the error in the title, while trying to link.

```
#ifndef BOOLEAN_H
#define BOOLEAN_H

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE !FALSE
#endif

#endif
```

indicating the error occurs in the line of the last `#endif`.

Comment: Why do you try to compile a header file?

Comment: @mafso: compiler will check many things, not just produce machine code. This helps detecting typos, omissions, etc.

Comment: Your problem is probably that the file you are compiling intentionally has no C code in it. I thought I did have C code in my file, but I hadn't saved it. If the file hadn't been saved at all, I would have gotten "No such file or directory" and "no input files" errors, but apparently I had saved a blank file, so I got this much more confusing error message instead. This is probably a common enough problem and this page is the first search result I got for "ISO C forbids an empty translation unit", so I figured I should note it here.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`gcc` when compiled with `-pedantic` reports a diagnostic when the translation unit is empty as it is requested by the C Standard. To make `gcc` happy, you can add a dummy `typedef` in the empty `.c` file:

```
typedef int make_iso_compilers_happy;
```

or

```
extern int make_iso_compilers_happy;
```

Comment: I would be interested in knowing why ISO C forbids empty translation units

Comment: If it's a header, how is it a translation unit?

Comment: @creanion, if you compile a file, it is a transalation unit. It doesn't matter what the extension is. So if you do `gcc -c foo.h` for example.